# Windows VBScript - Executing code with Eval

Tags: windows, vbscript, eval

I have a string in my vbscript file. I would like to execute the string as code. For example, the string could be 'msgbox("hello")'. However, the eval function only accepts numerical or string operations. How should I execute the code? I could always create a new file and write that string to the file, execute the file, and delete it, but I am looking for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, you can do this with an [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) statement. It's even referenced in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for the Eval function.