# Can you populate Classic ASP Constants (CONST) dynamically?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, constants

I am wishing to replace an include file with ~ 25 declared Constants by dynamically creating those constants from a Recordset (or Array). I have tried looping through a record set and have also tried populating a 2D array and then trying to set these Constants from the array values but it seems to take what is after the "Const" literal and not the value.

```
If (not rsVars.Eof) Then

cCount = rsVars.RecordCount
ReDim cArray(cCount - 1, 1)

For i = 0 To cCount - 1
  cArray(i, 0) = rsVars("VariableNm")
  cArray(i, 1) = rsVars("Value")
  rsVars.MoveNext
Next

End If

For i = 0 To cCount - 1

' Display the Array Elements - WORKS and Displays All Variables and Desired Values  
  Response.write "("&(i+1)&") " & cArray(i, 0) & " = " & cArray(i, 1) & "<br>"
' Attempt to set Constant Variables - this next line errors - "Name_redefined"
  Const cArray(i, 0) = cArray(i, 1)

Next
```

Comment: Constants are just that constant, allowing them to be set by a variable value defeats the purpose.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it but you might be able to set them using the [`ExecuteGlobal` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/342311f1(v=vs.84)) by passing a dynamically built string that is then interpreted as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows VBScript - Executing code with Eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248441/windows-vbscript-executing-code-with-eval)

Comment: You may create a dictionary (`Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"`) and add it to `Application` object and use that throughout your application.

Comment: @shahkalpesh wouldn't recommend storing COM objects like `Scripting.Dictionary` in `Application` variables, especially large ones.

Comment: Alternatively, one can create inc file on application startup and have those files included in pages where it is required. @user692942: It depends on how many records there are.

Comment: @shahkalpesh the OP already mentions at the start of the question that they are using an include file.

Comment: @user692942: I am suggesting modifying the include file at runtime on application start. What are you suggesting ?

Comment: @shahkalpesh right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467911/can-you-populate-classic-asp-constants-const-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment122785375_69467911)??

Comment: The include file can query a database table for the variables, no problem. Just with WordPress where it gets its settings from such re cords. before WordPress we all used to code CMS in ASP and by storing site settings in a table, the site owner can change config at any time. In fact I still use this method and it is much more secure than WP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the server.execute method to achieve this.
But it needs a FILE path to do so.

You will need to create a file dynamically using the FileSystemObject and pass the file's full path to the server.execute method to make those variables available as constants.
ex:
constants.asp

**Note**

Values will be CONSTANT Across user sessions and requests.

If you need a different set of constants by user, company, date etc, you will need to change the filename to include the unique constants-.asp and execute that file.

**References**

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_execute.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_ref_filesystem.asp