# How To Capture Form Data using OnChange

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I built up a page on my website as a place to perform testing of functions that I write (30 or 40 of them to date).  I use a  drop-down box to list the functions out by function name.  When one of them is selected, I use an onChange with "window.location" to fire that function via a Select Case structure, passing the index on the query string via this.selectedIndex in the OnChange.  All of this worked fine until I decided that I would also like the value of the selected option (name of the function being tested) as well (not just the index value).  I found through study that the window.location does not post any form values back, so they are not available. I kept on researching and found that the "location.reload" is supposed to post back the data, but that doesn't work either.

So, I figured that I could pass the option value data via the query string perhaps by using "this.selectedOptions", but that doesn't work either.  I have cut and paste a snippet of the code below, which again, works fine, but I can't get the text value of the selected option.

```asp
<form action="testcodepage.asp" method="post">
  <select class="rounded " name="cboSearchCategories "
     onChange='window.location="<%=sRootDomain%>/testcode/template/testcodepage.asp?TestCategory=" + this.selectedIndex;'

    <option value="Select One">Select One</option>
    <option value="SearchEquipmentDB()">SearchEquipmentDB()-Case #1</option>
    <option value="DisplaySingleItem()">DisplaySingleItem()-Case #2</option>
    <option value="CreateJSONSchema()">CreateJSONSchema()-Case #3</option>
    <option value="UnlockChilkatAPI()">UnlockChilkatAPI()-Case #4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Please let me know if there is a way to make this work, without using a submit button.  Much appreciated!  Note that this code is written using ASP Classic, but would be pertinent for any form submission.

Comment: Did you try `this.value`?

Comment: Hello James, I just tried that, and it works!  So the new onChange string is as follows:

onChange='window.location="<%=sRootDomain%>/testcode/template/testcodepage.asp?TestCategory=" + this.selectedIndex + "&TestName=" + this.value;'

It would be nice to know if there is a way to get ALL of the POST data (rather than having to put values on the query string), but this works for now.  I really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Why do any of that? Just pass the name of the function as the value of the `<select>` retrieve it from the form POST via `Request.Form("cboSearchCategories")` then call the server-side function using `ExecuteGlobal yourvariable` to execute the function, no JavaScript necessary.

Comment: @user692942 A Request.Form doesn't retrieve any POST data when using onChange=window.location.  This question is more about getting around that, than it is about the functionality of the page itself.  I have other pages that use the onChange and window.location code, and it is pertinent to know that you'll not get POST data using that technique to load a new page.  Just another item for me to fully understand.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248885/692942

Comment: If you really want to fire it `onchange` use `document.form.submit()`. To be clear `Request.Form` is only populated if you submit a form via POST either manually or via `.submit()`.

Comment: Correct.  I'll try that and get back to you with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Using the suggested "onchange="this.form.submit()" (thank you @user692942) solution works good, but I had to figure out how to also get the index value.  The following code resolves this.  Note that the very 1st solution also works (as suggested by @James), but isn't as practical, as I can't get all of the POST data that way.

```asp
Dim aDropDownValue
Dim sTestSearchCategory
Dim iCboIndex: iCboIndex = 0

<form action="testcodepage.asp" method="post">
  <select class="rounded" name="cboSearchCategories" id="cboSearchCategories" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="Select One|0" <%=IfSelected(sSearchCategory, "Select One")%>>Select One</option>
    <option value="SearchEquipmentDB()|1" <%=IfSelected(sSearchCategory, "SearchEquipmentDB()")%>>SearchEquipmentDB()-Case #1</option>
    <option value="DisplaySingleItem()|2" <%=IfSelected(sSearchCategory, "DisplaySingleItem()")%>>DisplaySingleItem()-Case #2</option>
  </select>
</form>

sTestSearchCategory = Trim(Request.Form("cboSearchCategories"))
If sTestSearchCategory <> "" Then
   aDropDownValue = Split(sTestSearchCategory, "|")
   sTestSearchCategory = aDropDownValue(0)
   iCboIndex = aDropDownValue(1)
End If

Select Case iCboIndex
  Case 1 ' Test the SearchEquipmentDB() function.
     Response.Write("Now testing the ") & sTestSearchCategory & " function." & "<br>"
  Response.End

  Case 2 ' Test the DisplaySingleItem() function.
     Response.Write("Now testing the ") & sTestSearchCategory & " function." & "<br>"
  Response.End

  Case Else
  Response.End

End Select
```

Comment: Why did you need the `selectedIndex`? If you just pass the function name as the value `ExecuteGlobal` can execute the function without the need for a `Select Case` statement.

Comment: @user692942, Because each test case contains debugging code and other code which calls the function, and then shows the results, etc.  Each of the functions are contained in dozens of external include files, which are included at the top of the page.  I do understand the use of ExecuteGlobal and do utilize it in the application itself, but not on this test page.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `addEventListener` on the form you and listen for the change event you can get the changed form field by `e.target` and the value you then be `e.target.value`.

```html
<form name="ThisForm" action="" method="post">
  <b>Select Test Category:</b>&nbsp;
  <select class="rounded" name="cboSearchCategories" id="cboSearchCategories">
    <option value="Select One">Select One</option>
    <option value="SearchEquipmentDB()">SearchEquipmentDB()-Case #1</option>
    <option value="DisplaySingleItem()">DisplaySingleItem()-Case #2</option>
    <option value="CreateJSONSchema()">CreateJSONSchema()-Case #3</option>
    <option value="UnlockChilkatAPI()">UnlockChilkatAPI()-Case #4</option>
  </select>
</form>
<script>
  document.forms.ThisForm.addEventListener('change', e => {
    window.location = "/testcode/template/testcodepage.asp?TestCategory="
      + e.target.value;
  });
</script>
```